# Get page in curl as text

Tags: curl, lynx

Is there any option for `curl` that saves a page as *text*?

I mean, in the same way a page can be saved in browser as *Text Files*. At least, Firefox has that option.

I need it for a script, I simply do something like

```
curl -s http://...
```

But it would make things much easier to deal with it without all html code.

I found an option for `lynx` that makes what I want: `lynx -dump`, but I'd rather use `curl`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can use `lynx` for this:

```
lynx -dump URL
```

UPDATE. Ops. Sorry. I did not see you know about lynx.

I advice to use `lynx` for this purpose. It often produces very readable output. Sometimes you should use `-width` option to increase width of the output.

Comment: That's disappointing... because `lynx` behaves different under `GNU/Linux` than under `cygwin` (add/remove an extra blank line). It makes me do different scripts for each platform or I have to check whether I'm under `cygwin`.Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I've just checked - lynx from xubunutu 14.04 from Virtual Box and Cygwin from the same my windows box gives the same outputs. Diff shows no diffs)

Comment: Don't know why, but for me show different outputs. I _resolved_ removing all blank lines with `sed`, so I can use same script.

Comment: @Albert: if you are already using sed, I suggest you try with `curl -s http://... | sed 's/<\/*[^>]*>//g' | <whatever_you_want>`, to remove all (well almost all) of the html tags.

Comment: This was great for my screenscraping with `xargs`, avoiding going through a long-running podcast with pagerized old episodes.

Answer (score 9):

You can consider [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/), a powerful tool to convert files from one markup format into another.

```
curl -s URL | pandoc -f html -t plain
```

It's just simple to use:

```
pandoc [OPTIONS] [FILES]
  -f FORMAT, -r FORMAT  --from=FORMAT, --read=FORMAT                    
  -t FORMAT, -w FORMAT  --to=FORMAT, --write=FORMAT                     
  -o FILE               --output=FILE                                   
                        --data-dir=DIRECTORY
```

Type `pandoc --list-input-format` and `pandoc --list-output-formats` to know the formats in which you can move.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use your `curl` command, and pipe it into `lynx`.
This is useful if you need to pass authentication or any specific curl parameters. For example:

```
curl --config auth.cfg $URL | lynx -stdin -dump -width=100
```

This passes auth.cfg file parameters to access the URL, and prints the html page in plain text (without html tags and escape characters).

Answer (score 1):

`curl` is a command to **retrieve files** from web servers, in the exact form as they are sent by the server. What you expect is to **convert the HTML file to plain text**, which is a completely different task. So you need another tool for this, as it's not the purpose `curl` has been designed for.